# FragmentTransaction not supported

Tags: android

i used min sdk 8 max sdk 19..i get error

Replace(int, android.app.fragement in fragementTransaction cannot be applied to (int.android.support.v4.app.fragement)

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: can you post some code, where you are getting warning?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `fragmentManager` is instance of `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. Try this code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

.......

fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your minsdk version to 11 or above as fragments are added on api level 11 and above
and in the fragment class you need this code

`fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`

Comment: Please accept my answer as well as it will be helpful for other users who will face the same problem and vote up also the answer @user3505360